# How do I rewrite a URL in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I rewrite URLs in ASP.NET 2.0?

I'd like to rewrite the following URL:

> Example : www.example.com/default.aspx?q=india

To this:

> www.example.com/india

How do I do that in ASP.NET 2.0?

Comment: Google your title and the first post is Scott Guthrie... http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use. This is open source url rewriter for .net.

http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/configuration

Comment: this link helped me to start working on url rewriting .. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [IIS Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module).

You can put the re-writes in your web.config for easy maintenance. For example:

```
<rewriteMap name="/fixurls">
   <add key="/LateOffers.aspx" value="/late-offers" />
</rewriteMap>
```

Comment: Thought about answering with this, but since he is interested in an old version of the framework, I figured he was not on the latest IIS either.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think URL rewriting doesn't have anything to do with the .NET version used, but with IIS only, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I've been successfully using Helicon ISAPI Rewrite (http://www.isapirewrite.com) for a while with ASP.NET 2.0.

Note that their 3.0 version is more Apache mod_rewrite compliant. 2.0 has some significant differences.