# Asp page: how to hide the real URL

Tags: asp.net, url

Can i know how to hide the real url of an aspx page??

Some like the forward in java in a servlet.

So if i have:

```
.../VerificaDisp.aspx
```

I want something like:

```
.../VerificaDisp
```

Thanks. Guys =)

Comment: If you don't use MVC you can use URL Rewriting as part of IIS.

Comment: You talk about context.RewritePath method???

Comment: URL Rewrite 2.0 >> iis.net

Comment: Possibly this is the duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603499/how-do-i-rewrite-a-url-in-asp-net-2-0/21603925#21603925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't use `route table`?

by this you can process request and forward request to page you want .

see [RouteTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

and, in your handler you can create a `aspx` page by this method to send request to that page:

```
BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath()
```

this is really great